# Spark how to merge two column based on a condition

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a spark dataFrame which has 3 column, and I want to merge two of theme based on the 3rd one, here is an example :

```
+---+---+---+
|AAA|bbb|ccc|
+---+---+---+
|AAA|BBB|  E|
|AAA|BBB|  R|
|AAA|BBB|  E|
|AAA|BBB|  R|
|AAA|BBB|  R|
|AAA|BBB|  E|
+-----------+
```

I want to use the value of column AAA when the value of column CCC is E and to use BBB when CCC is R
here is the output :

```
+---+---+
|NEW|ccc|
+---+---+
|AAA|  E|
|BBB|  R|
|AAA|  E|
|BBB|  R|
|BBB|  R|
|AAA|  E|
+-------+
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This can be done using `when`. (PySpark solution shown below)

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when
df.withColumn('New',when(df.ccc=='E',df.aaa).when(df.ccc=='R',df.bbb)).show()
```

Answer (score 0):

using SparkSql

```
SELECT
CASE
    WHEN CCC='E' THEN AAA    
    ELSE BBB
END AS new,CCC
FROM dataset;
```

Answer (score 0):

> Using spark Scala

with **when** and **otherwise** we not need to used again when if we have only two cases with respect to column.

```
var df=spark.createDataFrame(Seq(("AAA","BBB","E"),("AAA","BBB","R"),("AAA","BBB","E"),("AAA","BBB","R"),("AAA","BBB","R"),("AAA","BBB","E"))).toDF("AAA","bbb","ccc")
df.withColumn("New",when(col("CCC").equalTo("E"),col("AAA")).otherwise(col("BBB"))).show
```

Please find attached screenshot for same.

[image]